# Handling images in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing a api applicacion with Rails 5. From client side I have an Anuglar app.

I have the following requirements to do:

- Async upload of images. (Note that implies that the images have no attached to a model at the first time).
- The model to be create can have N images attached.
- For each uploaded image, create M specified thumbnails. (Note that also that thumbnails should be attached to the model.)

I have read about CarrierWave and paperclip but I don't found how can I do all of these requirements.

I will really appreciate any suggestion, lib, gem, etc that covers all of these requirements.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. If you can reword this question to pose a specific programming question (e.g. "I'm trying to do x, y, z with PaperClip") then you'd be back on topic.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I can't try anything because I don't found a gem that covers all requirements.

Comment: @Overflow012 the documentation for both `paperclip` and `carrierwave` will show you what tools are available to you, and both are sufficient for doing what you want. however, both would require you implement the handling as you describe within your application's back end. this "question" thus lacks direction, nor can it have any definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented something similar with CarrierWave gem. Assuming you want images attached to a model `Post`.

in the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, inverse_of: :post
end
```

you can then have a photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   mount_uploader :post_image, PostImageUploader
end
```

Then you can add this to `app/uploaders/post_image_uploader.rb`

```
class PostImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
    version :standard do
      process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]
    end

    version :thumb do 
      process resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
    end
end
```

since you are creating the images via an api, you'll have to convert the image to `Base64` string and send as a param. on this example the base64 string is in param `[:photo][:photo_data]` before sending it to the server. in `photos_controller.rb` have this:

```
def create
  @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
  @photo.post_image = decode_photo_data(params[:photo][:photo_data])

  if @photo.save
    render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo
  else
    render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end 
end

 #decode base64 data to an jpg image: 
 def decode_photo_data(photo_data)
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(photo_data))

    data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    data.original_filename = "upload.jpg"
    data.content_type = "image/jpg"

       # return decoded data
    data
 end

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:caption, :post_id)
  end
```

With this, when you make a post request to your create photo api endpoint with a body like this

```
{"photo": {"caption": "an image", "post_id": 1, "photo_data":<your image base64 string>}}
```

it will create a `photo` with both a `standard` and a `thumb` version for the `post` with an `id` of `1`.